# MySQL 5.7.17 out of memory crashes while creating triggers

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

Our MySQL 5.7.17 AWS RDS instance crashes with OOM. We did some research and came to the conclusion that it is not any particular SELECT query that causes it.

We have a use case that requires us to log changes to all of our tables (about 200) into a single AuditLog table. To achieve that we run a script that scans information schema and generates one trigger per table for the total of 200. An example trigger looks like this:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS data.sor_insert_AlignedObjective;
    delimiter //
    CREATE TRIGGER data.sor_insert_AlignedObjective  AFTER INSERT ON data.AlignedObjective FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    DECLARE primaryKeyVal, userVal VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE fieldVal, columnValue TEXT;
    DECLARE timeNow DATETIME;
    DECLARE clientID, contextCountryCode VARCHAR(36);
    DECLARE valueIndicator Boolean;
    SET primaryKeyVal = new.AlignedObjectiveID;
    SET userVal = user();
    SET timeNow = NOW();
    SET clientID = new.ClientID;
    SET contextCountryCode = new.Context_Country_Code;
    SET fieldVal = CONCAT('"',new.PerformanceObjectiveID,'"');
    IF fieldVal IS NOT NULL THEN
    SET columnValue = JSON_OBJECT("newValue",new.PerformanceObjectiveID);
    INSERT INTO log.EventLog (EventID, SchemaName, TableName, ColumnName, ActionType, PrimaryKey, ColumnValue, CreationDateTime, Context_Country_Code, ClientID, UserName)
    VALUES (@eventID, 'data', 'AlignedObjective', 'PerformanceObjectiveID', 'INSERT', primaryKeyVal, columnValue, timeNow, contextCountryCode, clientID, userVal); 
    END IF;
    SET fieldVal = CONCAT('"',new.RelatedPerformanceObjectiveID,'"');
    IF fieldVal IS NOT NULL THEN
    SET columnValue = JSON_OBJECT("newValue",new.RelatedPerformanceObjectiveID);
    INSERT INTO log.EventLog (EventID, SchemaName, TableName, ColumnName, ActionType, PrimaryKey, ColumnValue, CreationDateTime, Context_Country_Code, ClientID, UserName)
    VALUES (@eventID, 'data', 'AlignedObjective', 'RelatedPerformanceObjectiveID', 'INSERT', primaryKeyVal, columnValue, timeNow, contextCountryCode, clientID, userVal); 
    END IF;
    SET fieldVal = CONCAT('"',new._DeletedDateTime,'"');
    IF fieldVal IS NOT NULL THEN
    SET columnValue = JSON_OBJECT("newValue",new._DeletedDateTime);
    INSERT INTO log.EventLog (EventID, SchemaName, TableName, ColumnName, ActionType, PrimaryKey, ColumnValue, CreationDateTime, Context_Country_Code, ClientID, UserName)
    VALUES (@eventID, 'data', 'AlignedObjective', '_DeletedDateTime', 'INSERT', primaryKeyVal, columnValue, timeNow, contextCountryCode, clientID, userVal); 
    END IF;
    END; //
    delimiter ;
```

Observing the cloudwatch metrics for freeable memory we find that when we create triggers the amount of freeable memory drops precipitously. Following that, a few queries put it over the edge (or it does it on its own) and the daemon crashes with OOM.

What's more puzzling is that upon restart, the freeable memory drops quickly again, as if MySQL is trying to load something into memory.

The only configuration parameters that we modified relative to default AWS RDS for MySQL parameters are the following:

[image: Parameter comparison]

So we are a bit at a loss as to what could be the cause. Any thoughts?

Comment: *"To achieve that we run a script that scans information schema"*.  What happens if you run that same script, but comment-out the part that actually messes with the triggers?  Perhaps the scans of information_schema are the real issue.  It is particularly important when scanning information_schema **not** to casually use `SELECT *` unless you *need* all the columns.  You only want to ask for the columns you need, for reasons longer than a comment allows.  Thoughts?

Comment: If you're generating the triggers by querying all tables in information_schema - are you maybe generating the trigger for the log.EventLog table - if so you may be creating a race condition?

Comment: No triggers on log.EventLog, that was the first thing we checked.

Comment: To be honest, I am not 100% convinced it is triggers that cause the issue.